# Crashlytics fails to send request while behind proxy

Tags: android, proxy, crashlytics

I have an Android app running behind a proxy.

The use of this proxy is configured via a ProxySelector like that:

```
class MyProxySelector : ProxySelector() {

    private var noProxy = ArrayList<Proxy>()
    private var myProxy = ArrayList<Proxy>()

    init {
        noProxy.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
        myProxy.add(Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress("xx.xx.xx.xx", 8080)))
    }

    override fun select(uri: URI): List<Proxy> {

        // Don't use proxy when accessing local server, use proxy to access the rest of the world
        return if (uri.toString().startsWith(BuildConfig.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS))
            noProxy
        else
            myProxy
    }

    override fun connectFailed(uri: URI?, socket: SocketAddress?, exception: IOException?) {
        // Stub
    }
}
```

This proxy configuration is done as early as possible in the application (i.e, in the Application.onCreate()). The application works fine. HTTP requests are properly sent through the proxy when needed.

However, on application startup, Crashlytics fails to send requests. I have this error message:

> Fabric: Settings request failed.
>   io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to
>   settings.crashlytics.com/2a00:1450:4007:809::2003 (port 443) from
>   /fdeb:5a5a:dc47:11:1::17 (port 35702) after 10000ms

I suspect that Crashlytics sends requests before the Proxy is set.

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: did you resolve this? Was your problem just startup? i.e. later requests are always successful?

Comment: I did not find a solution to this. I just managed to get rid of the proxy. I don't recall whether or not later requests were successful but I don't think so since this first request seems to used to fetch some kind of crashlytics settings.

Comment: interesting thanks. I believe Crashlytics register a broadcast receiver for app start events, and that can run before your Applications onCreate (or without it) :-(